# Django: MultipleChoiceField in admin to carry over previously saved values

Tags: django, admin, modelform

I am having troubles to carry over previously selected items in a ModelForm in the admin.
I want to use the *forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple* widget since that is the most straightforward UI in this usecase. It works as far that when saving, the values are stored. But when editing the previously saved item, the values previously saved in this field are not reflected in the widget.

UI Example:

[image]

After posting (editing that item, returns it blank):

[image]

However, when not using the widget but a regular CharField when editing the item it looks like:

[image]

So for some reason the values are not represented by the checkbox widget?

Here's my simplified setup, models.py

```
POST_TYPES = (
    ('blog',      'Blog'),
    ('portfolio',     'Portfolio'),
    ('beeldbank',     'Beeldbank'),
)

class Module(models.Model):
    title         =   models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='title')        
    entriesFrom     =   models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
       return self.title
```

forms.py:

```
class ModuleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    entriesFrom = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
            choices=POST_TYPES, 
            widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple, 
            label="Pull content from", 
            required=False,
            show_hidden_initial=True) 

    class Meta:
        model = Module

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ModuleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if kwargs.has_key('instance'):
            instance = kwargs['instance']
            self.fields['entriesFrom'].initial = instance.entriesFrom

            logging.debug(instance.entriesFrom)
```

admin.py

```
class ModuleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ModuleForm
```

So when editing a previously saved item with say 'blog' selected, debugging on **init** returns me the correct values on self.fields['entriesFrom'] ([u'blog',]), but its not reflected in the checkboxes (nothing is shown as selected) in the admin.

*edit*

updated the ModuleForm class to pass on initial values, but nothing still gets pre-populated whilst there are a few values in the initial value ("[u'blog']").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

Setting the choices by a integer, instead of a string.

```
POST_TYPES = (
    (1,     'Blog'),
    (2,     'Portfolio'),
    (3,     'Beeldbank'),
)
```

Damn, that wasn't worth breaking my skull over.

Answer (score 2):

Might not be correct, but for my usecase, I did not want to replace the values with integers (as per the accepted answer). This was arrived at by a smidge of trial-and-error, and a lot of stepping through Django internals. Works for me, but YMMV:

```py
from django.forms.widgets import (
    CheckboxSelectMultiple as OriginalCheckboxSelectMultiple,
)

class CheckboxSelectMultiple(OriginalCheckboxSelectMultiple):
    def optgroups(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        # values come back as e.g. `['foo,bar']`, which we don't want when inferring "selected"
        return super().optgroups(name, value[0].split(","), attrs)
```

Comment: This works perfectly for an ArrayField storing strings.  I've spent hours trying to figure this out and this saved me.  Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not understanding your question completely, but it seems like you could simplify a little. Using ModelForms, I don't think any of your overriding the _*init*_ in your form is necessary. Try this and see if you get your desired behavior.

models.py

```
class Module(models.Model):
    POST_TYPES = (
        ('blog', 'Blog'),
        ('portfolio', 'Portfolio'),
    )

    title        =   models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='title')        
    entriesFrom  =   models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Pull content from', choices=POST_TYPES, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
       return self.title
```

forms.py

```
class ModuleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Module
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
admin.site.register(models.Module)
```

If my answer isn't what you're looking for, try clarifying your question and I'll see if I can help you out.

Comment: Well for the entriesFrom field, i want to use the forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple widget since that is the most straightforward UI in this usecase. It works as far that it saves the values, but when going back to the previously saved item, the values previously saved in the checkboxes are not shown.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function to remove string mark

```
from ast import literal_eval

literal_eval(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue, my changes haven't affected on save.
I use CharField in model, but in forms.py;

```
class ModuleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    my_field = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
            choices=POST_TYPES, 
            widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple,
            required=False,) 

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ModuleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if kwargs.get('instance'):
            self.initial['my_field'] = eval(self.initial['my_field'])
```

This form solution worked for me on MultipleChoiceField on Django Admin.